# Define Startup State in MoveIt

Tags: motion-planning, pose, moveit, robot, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

i want to declare the startup state of my UR5 Robot for motion planning in MoveIt (using a Python script). Every time i launch the demo file in RViz, the robot is lying flat on the ground (all joint states are zero). How can i define the start pose of the robot?
I already declared the following:

```
moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
rospy.init_node('ur_arm')
pub_pos = rospy.Publisher('arm_pos', Pose, queue_size=10)    

scene = PlanningSceneInterface()
robot = RobotCommander()
group = MoveGroupCommander("manipulator")
```

Thanks for your support. Im running ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255872/define-startup-state-in-moveit/) by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2017-03-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-01**:
Can you please include some text on what you've already tried? This has been asked a few times already, so if you've tried some things but they didn't work that would be good to include as it would avoid readers suggesting the same things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not Python specific.

Initial states of the robot when simulated with `demo.launch` can be set to named targets in `config/fake_controllers.yaml`.
See http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/fake_controller_manager_tutorial.html?highlight=fake#yaml-file-examples for an example.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on 2017-03-01**:
If i add

```
    initial:
      - group: arm
        pose:  home
```

where do i define what "home" is?

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-03-01**:
`home` has to be a named target.
These are defined in your robot's srdf file.
You can either add them by hand or use the [moveit_setup_assistant](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html#step-5-add-robot-poses)

**Comment by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on 2017-03-01**:
Thank you it worked!

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-07-10**:
I can't edit this answer, but the link is dead: http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/fake_controller_manager/fake_controller_manager_tutorial.html